# How do I update the password for Git?

Tags: macos, git, change-password

I'm using BitBucket with Xcode and Git for version control, and recently I changed all of my passwords (*thanks Adobe!*).

Unsurprisingly, I'm no longer able to push my local commits to my repository on BitBucket (`Authentication failed for 'https://______.git'`), but I'm forgetting how to update the cached password on my iMac. Somehow I've been unable to find it on Google or Stack Overflow, though it seems to me it should be rather straightforward...

Comment: It's probably stored in your OS X _keychain_ (the password store)

Comment: Could be in your .git/config file, if your username/password are just stored with the git url.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: If you are on macOS and nothing else works, try updating "Internet Password" github.com entry in Keychain Access app. Then set the new Personal Access Token (PAT) as password.

Answer (score 1392, accepted):

To fix this on macOS, you can use

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

A username and password prompt will appear with your next Git action (pull, clone, push, etc.).

For Windows, it's the same command with a different argument:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Comment: On Mac OS 10.12.2 and when I did the above - checked and double checked that I entered it correctly - and nothing happened.

Comment: Worked for me just now on 10.12.3 (Sierra). Had to do it twice though but that may have been a VPN/network issue

Comment: @b_dubb It might not do anything until the next time you reach out (push, pull,fetch) then you will be prompted for credentials.

Comment: @user2782001 I was using the osxkeychain helper, running the mac command did nothing. I suspect that if someone was not using the helper before, changing the configuration to use the helper, it would see that a password had not been entered for that remote, it would prompt, and everything would be fine the first time.  Subsequent changes of the configuration would not prompt. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855367/6251951) below worked for me.

Comment: Does not work on windows. Doesn't prompt for the new password

Comment: Worked perfectly on Sierra. So silly that it doesn't just ask you to re-login. It just fails with a `remote: Invalid username or password.`

Comment: This only worked for me (on sierra) up to the point where it began asking me for un/pw ... but it refuses to accept what I have demonstrated to myself over and over again to be the correct password.  I do have two-factor enabled, so I have to assume it is involved, but I'm not being prompted for anything related to that.

Comment: @JoshuaEricTurcotte I know this is way late, but if you have two factor enabled you need to generate an API token from your account settings in GitHub and use that for your password. Instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/

Comment: Did not work for me on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. git version 2.8.4

Comment: This does not seem to do anything. OSX El Capitan. git version 2.7.4

Comment: There is no visible immediate feedback, but it works on High Sierra. I had to clone a github repository before it actually asks for the password, it seems like it just sets a "dirty" flag for the next time you do a github request as @user2782001 mentioned.

Comment: For me the symptoms were showing like `remote: repository not found` just after I changed my Github user password on MacOS Mojave, I just followed the steps outlined here https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain. Great help.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder not to use `--global` if you have different accounts for different repos

Comment: Thanks for this!
Worked perfectly on Windows 10 using mingw64.

Comment: I ran command for Mac on Windows machine. It did not recognize the command but a popup opened to enter password, which I was looking for.

Comment: Windows solution worked for me (win10).

Comment: For mac you could try https://stackoverflow.com/a/67765064/1110305

Comment: on windows, you might be using system and not global, so then use `git config --system credential.helper wincred` instead

Answer (score 890):

None of the other answers worked for me on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4

Here is what I had to do:

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

Then run your git command (ex. `git push`) and reenter your username and password.

Comment: This saved me! I was storing it in composer, but it was also creating an auth.json which got annoying because I always forgot to add it to the .gitignore.

Comment: Thankyou that worked ! before then it was prompting me for password but even though I entered  new password authincation still failed.

Comment: This do nothing for me on Windows. After this command I've tried to push, and it was successful, so the password is still available for git

Comment: Worked for me on Win 10.  Password prompt popped up and didn't need to go to Control Panel

Comment: Works on Mojave 10.14

Comment: Worked on Win10. Firstly I used command from this answer and later simply `git pull` - Windows popup appeared prompting for a password. Thanks!

Comment: Woks on mac, but you have to do smt after this command, for example git pull or git fetch, so that it will prompt you to enter and save a new password.

Comment: After doing this if it says incorrect password on a push request, try pulling first to get a password prompt because this command only did unset the password.

Comment: Worked for me on linux

Comment: Also, this command worked on Windows 10, thank you very much.

Comment: This is the correct answer and works on all platforms.

Comment: Does not work for me on Linux but might work on other platforms.

Comment: `--global` should normally not be necessary.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, this did *not* immediately work as the username is lost and not automatically requested by the next git command. However, it worked seamlessly when the next command included the user name, so, e.g., `git pull https://YOUR_USER_NAME@github.com/...`.

Answer (score 778):

In Windows 10 with Git

Remove/update related Credentials stored in Windows Credentials in >>Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

Or you can just use the search bar and search for "CredentialManager" or "Windows Credentials", which should return an entry to open that Control Panel pane (at least for English users).

[image]

Comment: This was indeed the way. For users that have to work with the Dutch version of the OS: credentials ---> referentiebeheer

Comment: This was the simplest solution. All you need to do is edit. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, the path for me was Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager but best is to type Credential to jump right in.

Comment: @Everts what is OS of your machine?

Comment: My preferred method for opening anything on Windows, is to tap the Windows key and type the name of the thing in, and then press enter when it pops up in the search results. It's a lot faster and easier than navigating through explorer as suggested.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using git-fork and had to delete all credentials to our on-premise Azure Dev Ops server after Windows wanted me to change my domain password. Thereafter git push magically worked again without entering new credentials. Simply editing those credentials did not work.

Comment: @ZuBsPaCe, some times you have to close related program (git, vs or etc) to get fresh data

Comment: My credentials disappeared from here somehow, so I ran `git fetch` in one of my repos. Windows propmpted for authentication, and then populated the credentials here as expected.

Comment: It worked for windows 7 too (don't ask why our company is using ancient Windows)

Comment: If you wanna add one credential, the Internet or network address should be something like `git:https://yourrepo.address`, then your username and pass for it.

Comment: There is no git related generic credentials on my computer while I use git commit, push, pull everyday. Then how can we update the password? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh, hope it is a case of credentials at repo instead of Global. If this is the case then it will ask you to reenter credentials in case of failure or you can change it through command directly.  you can try >git credential reject

Comment: @ImranJaved Thanks for your reply. You can check my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913288/how-to-change-github-password-by-command-line-on-windows-mac

Comment: @Kamlesh, if you are stuck and there is no pending pull or push then I will recommend to refresh you repo clone.

Comment: @ImranJaved git pull / push / merge / commit all are working. But due to compromised my command line password, I want to change it. Not found any solution yet. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In German Windows the Credential Manager is called "Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung"

Answer (score 203):

The only way I could modify my git password was to go to Credential Manager in Windows (Windows Key + type 'credential') and edit the git entry under Windows Credentials  Generic Credentials. 
Note: Not listed alphabetically

Comment: The question was asked for macOS

Comment: @Saikat and yet, many of us with the same question for windows end up finding this SO question. It's almost as if the question itself while tagged macos isn't OS specific!

Comment: You can just remove rather than edit, and you'll be prompted on the next push/pull

Comment: There is no git related generic credentials on my computer while I use git commit, push, pull everyday. Then how can we update the password? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 130):

I had the same problem, and the accepted answer didn't help me because the password wasn't stored in the keychain. I typed:

```
git pull https://myuser@bitbucket.org/mypath/myrepo.git
```

Then console asked me for my new password.

Comment: I tried like this only but still credential pop is displaying, instead of reset password

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to reset captcha first. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me using GitLab. I deleted my access token and generated a new one.

Comment: This might be the best way. It accounts for all systems git, not only github, and provides a UI for ease of use. You may or may not need `git config --unset user.password`.

Answer (score 114):

In windows 10 as mentioned above by  @Imran Javed you can find Generic Credentials at :

**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager  --> Windows Credentials**

find your git server  and than you can update password by clicking edit button.

[image]

Comment: @halxinate which operating system you use ? This is for windows 10.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on Windows 7

Comment: There is no git related generic credentials on my computer while I use git commit, push, pull everyday. Then how can we update the password? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 67):

For Mac

**If you have multiple remote repositories** (Github, Bitbucket, Job, etc.)

1) run in the project directory

```
git config --unset user.password
```

2) run remote git command (ie. git push or git pull)

Git will prompt you to reenter your user.name and user.password for this repository

**Or you can do it globally** if you have only one remote repository

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

Answer (score 54):

None of the other answers worked for me on MacOS Big Sur 11.3.1

I had Two-Factor Authentication enabled on Github, this makes is so you will fail when entering your username and password even when they are correct.

Here is what I had to do:

`git config --global --unset user.password`

Then run your git command (ex. git push) and enter your username.
For the password you need to generate a Personal Access Token.

> Go to `https://github.com/settings/profile` select the `Developer Settings` on the right. Select `Personal Access Token` `Generate new token`. Copy the generated token and use it as the password in terminal.

Comment: This worked for two-factor authentication scenario.

Comment: Could you add the source for your quote at the end?

Answer (score 51):

If you are MAC user then you can open KeyChain Access Application from finder and then look for your account listed there. Just click on it and update your password.
Now give a try and things will fall in place.

link for reference: [Updating your credentials via Keychain Access](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)

Comment: This is what worked for me! It allows us to update the password from *one* repo. Some of the other suggestions on this page will effect everything that git touches.

Comment: This worked for me as well

Comment: This should be the right answer for mac users, this is how mac manages passwords

Answer (score 41):

running `git config --global --unset user.password` followed by any git command would prompt you to enter username and password.

```
git config --global --unset user.password
git push (will prompt you for the password)
git status (will not prompt for password again)
```

Comment: Well, calling the command git push (or pull) just gave me authentication error and access denied. Did not prompt me

Comment: This answer doesn't cover anything that isn't covered by Derek's.

Answer (score 36):

In my Windows machine, I tried [the solution of @nzrytmn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074326/4575793) i.e.,
Control Panel>Search Credentials>Select "ManageCredentials">modified new credentials under git option category corresponding to my username.
And then,

Deleted current password:

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

Added new password:

```
git config --global --add user.password "new_password"
```

And It worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for me. I have resolved the issue as described here: https://cmatskas.com/how-to-update-your-git-credentials-on-windows/

Comment: NOT WORKING DEAR, TRIED TWICE

Comment: Warning: this stores an UNENCRYPTED password in ~/.gitconfig.

Answer (score 31):

If your credentials are stored in the credential helper, the portable way to remove a password persisted for a specific host is to call `git credential reject`:

```
$ git credential reject
protocol=https
host=bitbucket.org
⏎
```

or

```
$ git credential reject
url=https://bitbucket.org
⏎
```

After that, to enter your new password, type `git fetch`.

Comment: warning: invalid credential line: ?
fatal: unable to read credential from stdin

Comment: That worked for me under Windows 10, other methods not. This should be probably the correct answer.

Comment: Its working in Mac too

Comment: Indeed, this is the most portable and correct of all answers and should be the main answer to this question. It also worked for me under Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Worked in Linux Mint. Reject the credential and it will ask you to enter the new access token.

Comment: Worked on KDE, thank you!

Answer (score 31):

### Token authentication

Given the new **token authentication requirement from August 13 2021**, this may be what you are looking for:

1. [Generate a new access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
2. Update the token used to access your repository:

   ```
   git remote remove origin
   git remote add origin https://[TOKEN]@github.com/[USER]/[REPOSITORY]
   git push
   ```

Comment: This solution worked for me, none of those above did, I want to specify that USER is not the username that u use to access to ur github account, but the user of REPO

Comment: Yes.  This is the only solution that worked for me.  One command one should run first is: 
```git remote -v```
so that one can see the existing [USER] and [REPO] parameters.

Comment: If the name of your personal access token is "token" and token value is "123" then [TOKEN] = token:123 . For github.com/[USER]/[REPO], copy the URL that points at your repository - everything after "https://".

Answer (score 19):

There is such a confusion on this question, as there is way too much complexity in this question. First MacOS vs. Win10. Then the different auth mechanisms.

I will start a consolidated answer here and probably need some help, if I do not get help, I will keep working on the answer until it is complete, but that will take time.

Windows 10: |

```
|-- Run this command. You will be prompted on next push/pull to enter username and password:
|      git config --global credential.helper wincred (Thanks to @Andrew Pye)
```

`
MacOS:

```
|
|-- 1. Using git config to store username and password:
|  git config --global --add user.password
|
|---- 1.1 first time entry
|  git config --global --add user.password <new_pass>
|
|---- 1.2 password update
|  git config --global --unset user.password
|  git config --global --add user.password <new_pass>
|
|-- 2. Using keychain:
|  git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
|
|---- 2.1 first time entry
|  Terminal will ask you for the username and password. Just enter it, it will be 
|  stored in keychain from then on.
|
|---- 2.2 password update
|  Open keychain, delete the entry for the repository you are trying to use. 
|  (git remote -v will show you)
|  On next use of git push or something that needs permissions, git will ask for 
|  the credentials, as it can not find them in the keychain anymore.
`
```

Comment: I updated your formatting tried to add the reference to **Andrew Pye**, but couldn't find something. Reformatting Renhuais comment: running `git config --global --unset user.password` and then `git push origin master` will ask you for username and password. Put that into the answer too?

Answer (score 18):

I was pushing into the repository for the first time. So there was no `HEAD` defined.

The easiest way would be to:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It will then prompt for the password, and once you enter that it will be saved automatically, and you will be able to push.

Comment: if i push from local to my remote server then which password i have to use ? Is this my remote server credential password or other ?

Comment: @Fawwad It's the password for the remote repository.

Comment: My remote server is not github.com. It is my dedicated server where i installed Git.

Comment: i understand how this would help you push the first time, but how this would help to update the saved password.

Comment: @Fawwad it doesn't matter what you're using. You still need to give the credentials that provide write access to the repository to which you want to write.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee, how is this related to the question of OP?

Comment: @DmitryKabanov read the whole answer on how I did reset the password

Answer (score 16):

If you are using github and have enabled 2 factor authentication, you need to enter a Personal access token instead of your password

First reset your password:

`git config --global --unset user.password`

Then, log to your github account, on the right hand corner, click on Settings, then Developer Settings. Generate a Personal access token. Copy it.

`git push`

The terminal will prompt you for your username: enter your email address.

At the password prompt, enter the personal access token instead.

Answer (score 11):

do these steps in Terminal:

1. Delete current password saved in your Mac

   ```
   git config --global --unset user.password
   ```
2. Add your new password by using this command, replace  with your new password:

   ```
   git config --global --add user.password <new_pass>
   ```

Comment: This way your password does get saved in history, and anyone who runs the history command can see it as plain text. To prevent it you can add an extra space before the command or run this command 'history -d 1234' with the right line ID afterwards

Answer (score 11):

you can change password through command line in 2 places, following would edit credentials to connect the repo

```
git config --edit
```

The credentials also can be changed at global using global parameter like below

```
 git config --global --add user.password "XXXX"
```

or set the credentials helper with

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

but if you have repo level credentials set the use the first command

```
git config --edit
```

Answer (score 9):

For MacOS based on the new rule to use password tokens from August 13 2021.

I tried all other terminal based answers but none worked.

1. Simply head to `Keychain Access`
2. Search for `github`
3. Right click on all github related items, including `vs-code`,
4. Delete all items
   [image]

Answer (score 8):

my password was good in github desktop preferences but wrong in the `.git/config` file

for me the only working solution was to manually edit the file:
`.git/config`

that contains this line:

```
url = https://user:password@github.com/user/repo.git
```

change password to the GOOD password because it was an older one for me

Answer (score 7):

I was able to change my git password by going to Credential Manager in Windows and deleting all the git entries under Windows Credentials  Generic Credentials.

When doing a git pull or git push, windows will ask for the new user/password itself.

Answer (score 6):

I would try to delete my account in Keychain Access and then run `git clone` again. Git will ask me for a new password.

Comment: This is what I chose to do. I had multiple github accounts stored in the Keychain. I chose to delete them all. Successfully pushed my local branch.

Comment: not a good answer. Re-cloning is way too much for this simple task

Answer (score 5):

Just clone one of your existing repos, this will prompt you for new credentials:
e.g.

```
git clone https://myuser@bitbucket.org/mypath/myrepo.git
```

(where `https://myuser@bitbucket.org/mypath/myrepo.git` is an address of one of your existing repos)

Answer (score 5):

on mac BigSur 11.2.3
I updated the credentials in the [key chain](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain) then I ran the command below.

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
```

I had to do this because no other solution in this thread worked for me after changing to token auth for github. github kept stating repository not found.
If this does not work try to combine this with the other commands for mac in this thread.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Source for this is: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Answer (score 4):

Tried everything but nothing worked. Then the following did work.

1. Before any of the above steps, lock and unlock the keychain again coz sometimes it sorta gets stuck.
2. Install the GitHub Desktop — it helps.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for how to reset access to the repository. By the example of GitHub. You can change your GitHub profile password and revoke all "Personal access tokens" in "Settings -> Developer settings" of your profile. Also you can optionally wipe all your SSH/PGP keys and OAuth/GitHub apps to be sure that access to the repository is completely blocked. Thus, all the credential managers, on any system will fail at authorisation and prompt you to enter the new credentials.

Answer (score 4):

Following steps can resolve the issue .....

1. Go to the folder `~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree`
2. Delete the file `{Username}@STAuth-bitbucket.org`
3. Restart Sourcetree
4. Try to fetch, *password* filed appear, give your new password
5. Also can run `git fetch` command in terminal and need to type password
6. Done

Answer (score 3):

None of the command line options from within terminal worked for me. Ultimately, I just opened up keychain manually, searched for 'git' under 'All Items', found an entry there and deleted it. That did it! Next time I tried a git pull from the terminal and it prompted me for new creds.

Comment: In Visual Studio Code, the terminal command's did not do anything for me. Opening KeychainAccess (not Keychain) searching and deleting the entry fixed the problem. When using BitBucket, search for bitbucket instead of git.

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, e.g. after OSX v.11.6, should go to KeyChain and search "git". And delete the relevant keys. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

For MAC users, using git GUI (**Works for Sourcetree**, may work for others as well). Would like to add a small remark to [Derek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703718/7138492). The original suggestion:

```
$ git config --global --unset user.password
```

should be followed by a *push*/*pull*/*fetch* **BUT** it might not work when done from the GUI. The %100 working case would be to do the very first consecutive prompt-triggering git command from console. Here is an example:

1. Locate to your git repository root directory
2. Type in `$ git config --unset user.password`
3. Proceed with a git commend of your choice in terminal e.g.: `$ git push`

Then it will ask you to provide the new passoword.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/version-control-systems1/403-forbidden-error-message-when-you-try-to-push-to-a-github-repository#Cause), they explain it in a very easy way but basically, we just need to execute a `git remote set-url origin "https://<yourUserName>@bitbucket.org/<yourRepo>"` and next time you do a `git pull` or a `git push` you will have to put your password.

Comment: This does not work if your user name is an email address, though

Answer (score 1):

to update the password, open terminal and just do the following:

1. run git config --global --unset user.password
2. run "git pull" and you will be prompted to enter username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a git pull of any of your repository and you will be prompted to enter your new  password.

Comment: This used to work, but it doesn't work anymore. @Dan Leonard's solution works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (on Windows 10, Git version 2.34.1.windows.1, using Personal Access Token with SAML SSO enabled by my org):
when I issued
git pull
in my repo, I received the error message

ERROR: The `xxx' organization has enabled or enforced SAML SSO. To access
this repository, you must use the HTTPS remote with a personal access token
or SSH with an SSH key and passphrase
that has been authorized for this organization. Visit
https://docs.github.com/articles/authenticating-to-a-github-organization-with-saml-single-sign-on/ for more information.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I found that in my .git/config file I had this:
url = git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git

The link in the error message above stats to use SAML SSO (Personal Access Token, PAT) so I changed it to
url = https://www.github.com/myorg/myrepo.git

This time when issuing a git command like
git pull
I was presented with a login dialog where I could provide my PAT token and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I use the git extension on Visual Studio Code to access my company's git repo on Windows Azure. Originally I used command below to login:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:password@dev.azure.com/foo
```

After my password expired, I couldn't find my credential in the Windows Credential Manager. So I removed remote in the REMOTES section of VS Code, then added it back. When I clicked the Fetch button and it prompted me to choose a Windows credential. I chose the one I used to login to Windows and it connected to git repo successfully. I then also found the credential in the Windows Credential Manager.