# Git credential helper - update password

Tags: git, github, windows-7-x64, change-password, git-credential-winstore

I'm currently using GitHub over HTTPS and have the latest version of Git installed (1.9.0) along with the Git credential helper on Windows 7.

On setting up my environment, I told git-credentials to permanently remember my username and password.

I've recently updated my GitHub password via the website and I'm now no longer able to push/pull/fetch, etc.

How I would go about updating my password on git-credentials helper on Windows 7?

Comment: Simple, use  "git config --global credential.helper wincred" and enter userID and password; then this will be stored for you, next time you change your password, rerun above command.

Comment: If all else fails, and you're using TortoiseGit, you might want to try an action via that. For example a pull or fetch using Tortoise will prompt for the password, which you can then update. This seems to then overwrite the Git Bash cache, and you can use bash once more.

Comment: @AkshayLokur This does not work for me, I get a message: "error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value".

Comment: In addition to the comment by @AkshayLokur I had to follow the top comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11693074/3642162)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the password for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git)

Answer (score 385, accepted):

None of these answers ended up working for my Git credential issue. Here is what did work if anyone needs it (I'm using Git 1.9 on Windows 8.1).

To update your credentials, go to *Control Panel* → *Credential Manager* → *Generic Credentials*. Find the credentials related to your Git account and edit them to use the updated password.

Reference: *[How to update your Git credentials on Windows](https://cmatskas.com/how-to-update-your-git-credentials-on-windows/)*

Note that to use the Windows Credential Manager for Git you need to configure the credential helper like so:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

If you have multiple GitHub accounts that you use for different repositories, then you should configure credentials to use the full repository path (rather than just the domain, which is the default):

```
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if `git config --list` contains  `credential.helper=wincred`.

Comment: Worked for me - thank you - and learnt about Windows credential manager too.

Comment: This. changing the password didn't work but I deleted the credentials and then git push asked for credentials again and it worked.

Comment: I think it works for window 8.1 and window 10 also. In my case: window 10 Pro, git 2.17

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I used to be able to re-submit my pull, fetch, or push and I would be prompted to enter my new password. For some reason that no longer works. Thanks for teaching me about the Credential Manager!

Comment: For anyone that (like me) removes the stored credentials hoping for another prompt, but the prompt doesn't show. From Credentials Manager, you can `ADD` a `Generic Credential` with an address of `git:http://yourserver:port/`. Http or Https is the same, the important bit is the `git:` at the start.

Comment: Many thanks for this post. Our bitbucket is not using HTTPS or SSH. After running the second command setting `useHttpPath` as true it stopped messaging Authentication failed.

Comment: THANK YOU. Updating in the Control Panel's credential manager did the trick! I put my login instead of personal access token, so needed to update.

Comment: Why the heck isn't it the default to use the full path?

Comment: This doesn't only work with `wincred` but also with the credential manager core that comes with recent git version. Therefore you can use `git config --global credential.helper manager-core` which also stores the credential in the above mentioned Windows Credential Manager (German: Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung). Tested with git 2.31.1.

Comment: "To update your credentials, go to Control Panel → Credential Manager → Generic Credentials." In Windows 10, there is an extra step: : Control Panel → Credential Manager → Windows Credentials → Generic Credentials.

Comment: For non-English Windows systems, you might look for something akin to "references" instead of "credentials". Worked on Windows 7. (Translated: `Configuration screen > User accounts and parental control > Reference management`.)

Answer (score 130):

On my first attempt to Git fetch after my password change, I was told that my username/password combination was invalid. This was correct as git-credential helper had cached my old values.

However, I attempted another **git fetch** after restarting my terminal/command-prompt and this time the credential helper prompted me to enter in my GitHub username and password.

I suspect the initial failed Git fetch request in combination with restarting my terminal/command-prompt resolved this for me.

I hope this answer helps anybody else in a similar position in the future!

Comment: Just restart Git Bash, it will prompt a dialog to enter new username / password.

Comment: For the record, I was able to workaround this by doing another pull/fetch without restarting my Powershell session on Windows 7. Windows prompted me for my new creds on the second attempt.

Comment: restarting the console/app made "wincred" work for me. ( I had to restart my console and "Atom" and everything worked fine )

Comment: Entering any git command which requires credentials a second time seems to do this, not just `git fetch`, it also worked on a second `git clone`.

Comment: thank you very much! Every time I change my domain password, I have to remember how to update my credentials.Git fetch - It worked for me!

Comment: Yup, this was the one.

Answer (score 102):

**Solution using command line for Windows, Linux, and MacOS**

If you have updated your GitHub password on the GitHub server, in the first attempt of the `git fetch/pull/push` command it generates the **authentication failed** message.

Execute the same `git fetch/pull/push` command a second time and it prompts for credentials (username and password). Enter the username and the new updated password of the GitHub server and login will be successful.

Even I had this problem, and I performed the above steps and done!!

Comment: @ Vincent: what is the issue you are getting??

Comment: I just get repeated  remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for

Comment: @RichMeister: From second time it will ask for username/password. Just provide your username/new_password.

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS with cached credentials after a password change. First time get 'Authentication Failed for ...' . Tried again and was prompted for credentials, enter userid and new password, and now working again

Comment: This is the best/easiest answer

Comment: Sadly not working for me on MacOS Big Sur. Git just keeps using the old name/password credentials.

Comment: Worked on Windows. I was already logged in to github so I didn't even have to enter my username/password when the browser popped up.

Comment: does not work on Ubuntu

Comment: Works like a charm for me, by far the best answer. (Windows 10)

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 & VSCode with WSL.

Answer (score 102):

If you are a Windows user, you may either remove or update your credentials in Credential Manager.

In Windows 10, go to the below path:

*Control Panel* → *All Control Panel Items* → *Credential Manager*

Or search for "credential manager" in your "Search Windows" section in the Start menu.

Then from the Credential Manager, select "Windows Credentials".

Credential Manager will show many items including your outlook and GitHub repository under "Generic credentials"

You click on the drop down arrow on the right side of your Git: and it will show options to edit and remove. If you remove, the credential popup will come next time when you fetch or pull. Or you can directly edit the credentials there.

Comment: After trying other options only this one worked for me. I found info here: https://cmatskas.com/how-to-update-your-git-credentials-on-windows/

Comment: Note: this control is NOT ACCESSIBLE THROUGH METRO UI "CONTROL PANEL"!
You have to run `control.exe` manually to see this control.

Comment: This helped a lot! I didn't even know that this tools existed.

Comment: This helped a lot.

Comment: There is no git related generic credentials on my computer while I use git commit, push, pull everyday. Then how can we update the password? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

First find the version you are using with the Git command `git --version`. If you have a newer version than 1.7.10, then simply use this command:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Then do the `git fetch` , then it prompts for the password update.

Now, it won't prompt for the password for multiple times in Git.

Comment: This doesn not answer the question

Comment: @disklosr Yes it does. It forces Git to prompt for the updated password the next time you perform a remote action.

Comment: @Nilpo What is a "remote action" then?  Should not "git push origin xxx" be a remote action?  It isn't doing it. instead I get remote: Invalid username or password.

Comment: It worked for me. After executing this command. Do "git fetch", you will be prompted for credentials, provide it.

Comment: Why `--global`? Don't I risk to get re-asked for all my repositories instead of just the one affected?

Answer (score 45):

It seems to me that the answers here are outdated. For me using Git v2.15.0 issuing `git credential reject` like this did the job:

```
$ git credential reject
protocol=https
host=github.com
<Empty line here>
```

And then to set the new username & password:

```
$ git credential fill
protocol=https
host=github.com
<empty line here>
```

After this, if the credentials now work on the desired target host, we should use `git credential approve` -as mentioned in [typical use of Git credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential#_typical_use_of_git_credential) (step 4)- to tell the credential helpers to mark the credentials as approved and reuse them in future connections.

Comment: For me, doing the `git credential fill` part as-is, it generated automatically the old wrong password; I've had to set the new one manually with this command for it to work; anyway, thanks, this answer helped me with this problem!

Comment: Upvote to the top! How much wasted time reading outdated solutions. Actually Git Credential Manager is to blame here I think for having to go through pain when domain passswords are rotated.

Comment: after ```fill```, shouldn't we use ```approve```?

Comment: On my machine `git credential reject` never completes

Comment: @ThomasWeller you have to hit enter to leave an empty line there, then it completes.

Comment: You are welcome @DavidCallanan! It's funny, the answer is pretty buried under the other answers, but still helping some people.

Comment: You saved my life, bro

Comment: +1 for giving a git-based solution instead of a windows based one. I'm running linux and needed to switch from a password to a PAT and this was the only answer that worked.

Comment: to clarify in case others are as ignorant as me:  after verifying that the new credentials work, when you enter `git credential approve`, enter the same 2 lines again as the other calls to `git credential`:  `protocol=https` followed by `host=github.com`.

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear. It looks like one is editing a text file or something here. Just a heads up for everyone else: This is just multi-line CLI input.

Answer (score 27):

FWIW, I stumbled over this very same problem (and my boss too, so it got more intense).

The instant solution is to delete or fix your Git entries in the Windows Credential Manager. You may have a hard time finding it in your localized Windows version, but luckily you can start it from the good old <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> run dialog with `control keymgr.dll` or `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager` (or `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` if you prefer the classic look). Or put this in a batch file for your colleagues: `cmdkey /delete:git:http://your.git.server.company.com`.

In Microsoft's Git Credential Manager this is [a known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/750) that may be fixed as soon as early 2019 (so don't hold your breath).

**Update (2020-09-30)**: GCM4W seems to be more or less abandoned (last release more than a year ago, only one commit to master since then named, I kid you not, "Recreate the scalable version of the GCM Logo"). But don't despair, with Microsoft now going Core, there is a shiny new project called [GCM Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core), which seems to handle password changes correctly. It can be installed standalone (should be activated automatically, otherwise activate e.g. with `git config --system credential.helper manager-core`) but is also included in the current Git for Windows 2.28.0. For more information about it, see [this blog post](https://github.blog/2020-07-02-git-credential-manager-core-building-a-universal-authentication-experience/).

Comment: Understanding the Windows Credential Manager by using the Control Panel UI is great but gets tiresome when you have to update on all machines. This single command is great since it accomplishes the same thing (removes the existing invalid credentials) which forces git to prompt for the credentials again the next time it needs them.  


On Windows Server 2016, command syntax to remove credential is slightly different:   
    `cmdkey /delete:git:https://your.git.server.company.com`

Comment: `/delete{:<TargetName>}` is the [official syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey), but I found that the shortcut `/del <TargetName>` also works, at least in Windows 10 (1803).

Comment: great idea for an alias! ```delpw = !cmdkey /delete:git:$(git remote get-url $1)```. Usage: ```git delpw origin``` (ps: /del didn't work here, Win 10 as well)

Answer (score 22):

Working solution for Windows:

Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Generic Credentials

[image]

Comment: This will only work if you are logged as the user whose credentials you want to change; if you run git bash as admin and you are not admin, or you are changing credentials for a different user, this method won't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: For Windows 10 it is named: 

Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your Credentials > Windows Credentials, search for the git credentials and edit

Comment: There is no git related generic credentials on my computer while I use git commit, push, pull everyday. Then how can we update the password? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just `cd` in the directory where you have installed git-credential-winstore. If you don't know where, just run this in Git Bash:

```
cat ~/.gitconfig
```

It should print something looking like:

```
[credential]
    helper = !'C:\\ProgramFile\\GitCredStore\\git-credential-winstore.exe'
```

In this case, you repository is C:\ProgramFile\GitCredStore. Once you are inside this folder using Git Bash or the Windows command, just type:

```
git-credential-winstore.exe erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
```

Don't forget to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice after `protocol=https`.

Answer (score 7):

None of the current solutions worked for me with git bash 2.26.2.
**This should work in any case if you are using the windows credential manager.**

One issue is the windows credential manager runs for the logged user. In my case for example, I run git bash with right click, run as admin. Therefore, my stored credentials are in a credentials manager which I can't access with the windows GUI if I don't login to windows as admin.

To fix this:

- Open a cmd as admin (or whatever user you run git bash with)
- Go to windows/system32
- Type `cmdkey /list`. Your old credentials should appear here, with a part that reads ...target:**xxx**...
- Type `cmdkey /delete:xxx`, where xxx is the target from the previous line

It should confirm you that your credentials have been removed. Next time you do any operation in git bash that requires authentication, a popup will ask for your credentials.

Comment: **Accessing Credential Manager**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0

Answer (score 6):

For Windows 10 it is:

Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your Credentials > Windows Credentials, search for the git credentials and edit

Comment: There is no git related generic credentials on my computer while I use git commit, push, pull everyday. Then how can we update the password? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have reset your password, hence you are getting Auth failure error in the git bash command window. (it does not show popup where you could enter new password).

In the git bash cmd window enter following command:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Some times it will show popup to enter the new password
or Sometimes popup will be displayed when you are trying to do `$git clone` ..command

Answer (score 1):

If you keep getting "fatal: Authentication failed for  "https://......git" and you are unable to update the password.

> 1. $ git config --global credential.helper wincred
> 2. git clone -b  ..git
> 3. Popup will be displayed for username password
> 4. enter the new password