# problem while i was pushing my code to github.com, someone has got main access to github from my PC,

Tags: github, git-bash

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to ravi5026/web-server.git denied to vnaresh007.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ravi5026/web-server.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

where can I delete vnaresh007 and put my own access. My credentials are set properly.

Comment: Include output of `git config user.name`

Comment: what will this command do

Comment: It should output to which user has git been configured

Comment: it has given ravi5026

Comment: What about email? `git config user.email` is it yours?

Comment: yes that is also mine

Comment: Have you set up using ssh?

Comment: i had previously one ssh in the directory and i deleted that directory and created a new ssh and i added this new key to github . then i was trying to push my application to github it is showing this error , some one has created that key without my knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Check your git **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)**: this is what has cached the wrong credentials.

```
git config credential.helper
```

On Mac, just open your keychain access->search for github.com related file->and edit credentials there.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/setup/keychain-access.png]

See  "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)"

On Windows for example, that would be the [Windows Credential Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).
Open the Windows Credential Store, and see if the first user is registered there: delete that entry, and you will be able to authenticate with the second user.

(Here is an example for BitBucket; the same idea applies to GitHub)

[image: https://kwilson.io/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/4-store.png]

In command-line, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413943/6309):

> ```
> git credential reject
> protocol=https
> host=github.com
> <empty line here>
> ```
>
> and then to set the new username & password:
>
> ```
> git credential fill
> protocol=https
> host=github.com
> <empty line here>
> ```
>
> Type `git help credential` for detailed info.