# --global@github.com is coming up when I try to push my code to github

Tags: git, github

I couldn't find an answer to this and maybe I'm just blindly missing a step here, but whenever I try to push my code to github and use the `git push -u origin` master it prompts password for "--global@github.com":

I enter my password for my account and it says

```
Password for 'https://--global@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 
'https://github.com/richardquirarte/QRealty.git/'
```

I've already used git config --global user.email and verified it was my email there, but it keeps bringing that up.

Again, sorry if this is an easy fix, I just could not find an answer for this anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You probably had some bad config.

Try resetting the remote URL and your user name first:

```
git config --global user.name "some user name"
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/richardquirarte/QRealty.git
```

Comment: With GitHub, you have to use the GitHub credentials. It has nothing to do with those settings, Those settings are only for committing code

Comment: @CodeWizard But anyway, it seems like the problem is that the HTTP authentication username is set to `--global`, which could be some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a `git config --global` gone wrong.

Try `git config -l | grep global` and see if you have any configuration with "`global`" in it.

If not, check your `git config credential.helper` and see if you have to remove the user `--global` associated with the GitHub URL (see "[problem while I was pushing my code to github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53493376/6309)").

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but I had the same issue and figured it out.
I had accidentally set my credential username as --global somehow, so when I was prompted to login, I was prompted to login to --global@github.com.

To fix this:

```
git config --global credential.username "your github username here"
```

To make sure the credential username is correct:

```
git config -l
```

Now push your code.

```
git push
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using https which require a password for any interaction with the server.
It's not hard to solve it but instead I'm recommending you to switch to ssh and you will not have to use passwords anymore.

Read his doc on how to.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

To make it short:

- Generate ssh key
  Open git bash and type: `ssh-keygen`
- Once the ket is created copy it (the path to the public will be printed in your terminal)
- Add the key to your GitHub account
- Update the repo URL to your new URL

  ```
  git remote set-url origin <ssh url>
  ```

Comment: The answer have nothing with the question. The question is about bad remote URL in local `.git/config`.