# How to ask Gitbash to authenticate me again after my authentication failed the first time?

Tags: git-bash

Git bash asked for my username and password and I incorrectly entered my password on accident. It won't prompt me again for my user name and password so I can't do any git commands. Is there a command I can use to have it prompt me for the username and password again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with https, you need to remove that URL from the credential storage you are using.

See:

- "[Managing Remotes / Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain
  Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)", if you are on MacOS
- "[Windows Credential Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53493376/6309)" for Windows (for command-line: "[How to sign out in Git Bash console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)")

  ```
  git credential-manager reject <url>
  ```

Comment: I'm on Windows. How would I know if I'm working with https? Also what is the URL in the <url> :  git credential-manager reject <url>

Comment: @Anna By typing `git remote -v` in your repo. If the origin URL starts with `https://aserver/auser/arepo`, you are using an https URL. Then the command would be `git credential-manager reject https://aserver` (but you can also remove it through the GUI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53493376/6309)

Comment: when I type `git remote -v` it shows this: `origin  https://github.ncsu.edu/engr-csc326-spring2019/csc326-OBP-204-7.git (push)`. This would be a https URL, right?

Comment: @Anna yes, the one with the wrong credentials cached.