# How to resolve "remote: You (@user) must accept the Terms of Service in order to perform this action." issue?

Tags: git

I trying to push my local branch code to the master of a new repo. These are Gitlab repos. But I keep getting this error -

> remote: You (@user) must accept the Terms of Service in order to perform this action. Please access GitLab from a web browser to accept these terms.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/project/project-ios.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

@user is not me. I don't know what is happening.

I committed my local branch, open another remote on gitlab and on terminal wrote

```
git push https://gitlab.com/new_project/new_project-ios +local_branch:master
```

which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002080/1246639)!.

The person @user was working on a different repo before me. The repository I'm working in is created a few months ago and this person was not added as a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @user is not me

That means your local Git installation must use a credential helper which has cached the credentials for "user"

```
git config credential.helper
```

You could either:

- use an SSH URL (`git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:new_project/new_project-ios`), provided you have registered your SSH key to your GitLab account
- or [delete the credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211181/6309):

  ```
   git credential-manager reject gitlab.com
  ```

(on MacOS: see "[Managing Remotes / Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain
Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)")

Comment: Thanks. Can you change the username on the question?

Comment: @SomoyDasGupta No problem. I just did.