# Where does Android studio store git passwords?

Tags: git, android-studio

When pushing some changes using Android studio (on Windows if that's relevant) I accidentally clicked the save password option.

Where are these credentials stored and how do I remove them?

Comment: Would my 2019 answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54248265/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vonc linked me in a comment to [Signed Into Wrong Git Account in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247697/signed-into-wrong-git-account-in-android-studio/54248265#54248265)

I tried firing up "git bash" and checking for credential.helper, it was not set but I don't know whether that was because it really isn't set or because git bash and andriod studio use different settings. So I deemed this inconclusive.

I then tried another link in that answer which suggested going to file->settings->system-settings->passwords, this told me that keepass was being used and gave me an option to clear the database. Unfortunately there did not seem to be a way to view a list of what passwords were in the database.

I cleared the keepass database and it now prompts me for a password, so presumablly my password was stored there. I would have liked more positive confirmation though.