# Can't push changes from my local system to origin, even after adding public ssh key to Git Hub

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a new system (MacBook Pro) and want to set it up such that it can directly push to my remote repository on GitHub. The steps I followed were:

1. Generated an ssh key using the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.
2. Copied the content from `id_rsa.pub` into the SSH key area of my Github account.
3. Created a repository on GitHub.
4. Copied the repository url (https) into my existing local project using `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repo.git`.
5. Took a pull using `git pull origin master` (which worked without errors).
6. While pushing the new changes using `git push origin master` I got the below error.

```
remote: Permission to UserName/repo-name.git denied to name.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/UserName/repo-name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

**Question**: 
 
 1. Why am I getting the **permissions denied** error even after adding the SSH key to Github? Shouldn't GitHub consider my system to be trusted device after adding an SSH key? 
 2. How do I add my system as a trusted device so that I don't get the **permissions denied** error?

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Why am I getting the permissions denied error even after adding the SSH key to Github?

Because you are using an SSH key, which has nothing to do with HTTPS authentication (based on username/password)

> How do I add my system as a trusted device so that I don't get the permissions denied error?

Either set the proper SSH URL

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
           ^^^^^^^
```

This is case sensitive, and the username must be the GitHub one, where your repo resides.
It has nothing to do with `git config user.name`/`user.email` (which are not used *at all* for authentication, only for commit authorship)

Or you keep your current HTTPS URL, but you check if you have a credential manager caching wrong credentials:

```
git config credential.helper
```

For instance, [for a manager one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53493376/6309), you can reject old /fill new credentials (GitHub Username/password) associated to `github.com`.

Comment: HTTPS repository URL was my problem

Comment: @HuyPhạm Good catch, well done.

Answer (score 0):

You set the origin to `https` using an `ssh` configuration. Try to set your remote to `ssh` instead:

```
git remote set-url git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Comment: I've tried the above and it didn't work. The permission denied error is still there.

Comment: Did you set your user and email in the git configuration?

Comment: Yes. Using the following: git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME" 
and git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"

Comment: Then you can check your ssh connection following this guide: https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection.

Comment: I followed the guide and ended up with this: "Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: Cool! Did your retry to push?

Comment: There must be a typo somewhere, I suggest you to redo the whole process following [the official guide](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) (I don't know which steps you've followed!)