# How to fix git push name?

Tags: git, github

When i try to *git push*, i see this message:

> remote: Permission to Karetski/univercube.git denied to PavelMetsko.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Karetski/univercube.git/': The requested URL
>   returned error: 403

But in git config i see another user.name

> ```
> push.default=simple
> core.autocrlf=true
> user.email=karetski@gmail.com
> user.name=Karetski
> core.repositoryformatversion=0
> core.filemode=true
> core.bare=false
> core.logallrefupdates=true
> core.ignorecase=true
> core.precomposeunicode=true
> remote.origin.url=https://github.com/Karetski/univercube.git
> remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> branch.master.remote=origin
> branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
> ```

How to fix this thing? I need "Karetski" username instead of "PavelMetsko"

Comment: .gitconfig is stored in 3 places. Per-system, per-user and per-repository. They can overwrite each other. Have you checked all of them?

Comment: I check --global config and repository config. Where can i find other? I use OS X Yosemite

Comment: Git doesn't provide a user name (nor password).  When using https as your protocol, it's a "credential helper" that provides these.  See https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/ for details.  (Using ssh, git still doesn't provide a user name or password either, but the setup seems a bit more straightforward to me with ssh.)

Comment: Thank you @torek . Your answer is amazing. It really helps!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the password for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git)

Answer (score 1):

`user.name` is not for access control, it is what is used for your commits.

> user.name
>
> Your full name to be recorded in any newly created commits. Can be overridden by the GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_NAME environment variables. See git-commit-tree(1).

What you need to set are your [credentials](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html).

```
[credential "https://github.com/Karetski/univercube.git"]
    username = Karetski
```