# How to change the git password using command prompt?

Tags: git, credentials

Let's say my git username is 'gitme' and the password is 'gitpass'. how do I change the password to 'gitpass1'? Please let me know.

Comment: changing the bitbucket password did the  trick

Comment: git has no access control mechanism at all, this all depends on what hosting system you are using.

Comment: Please add more information to your question like: What system are you using? *Nix, OSX or Windows. What collaboration service are you  using? Github, gitolite, bitbucket etc...

Comment: For future readers, to change the password Git uses (instead of changing GitHub password): [macos - How do I update the password for Git? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git)

Comment: And for windows users, also check Control panel > User accounts > Manage windows credentials. You will find the stored password for each of the repositories listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can put the password in .netrc file (_netrc on windows). From there it would be picked up automatically. It would go to your home folder with 600 permissions.
- a new option is to use the credential helper. Note that credentials would be stored in clear text in your local config using standard credential helper. credential-helper with wincred can be also used on windows.

Usage examples for credential helper

```
git config credential.helper store - stores the credentials indefinitely.
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'- stores for 60 minutes
```

Comment: Thanks! If i have a problems with the previous solution I will try this next

Comment: I don't think this is the correct solution for your question. On the other hand, storing a password in a file is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

To reset/change your password in GitHub visit this [website](https://github.com/password_reset).

- Enter the email address associated with your personal GitHub account.
- GitHub will email you a link that will allow you to reset your password. You must click on this link within 24 hours of receiving the email. If you don't receive an email from GitHub, make sure to check your spam folder.
- After clicking on the link in your email, you'll be asked to enter a new password.

Comment: I have 2 passwords. One to login into github account on github website while another password is used to pull / push github repository. I have to change the second password not github account password. Kindly suggest how can we do? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

to change password in Bitbucket

1. Login to Bitbucket using current username & password
2. Goto Manage Account(top right corner)
3. Click Change Password, then enter old password and new password