# Can't change username and password from git

Tags: git, passwords

I use git extension.
I wanted the password and username to be store in cache so I used: 
git-credential-winstore.
It worked fine until I had to change the password in my computer (win7) and it asked me again to insert password. I inserted a wrong password and it stores in the cache and I can't change it.
I tried to uninstall git and no use.
I deleted from .gitconfig file in user\myUser the lines:

```
[credential]
helper = !'C:\\Users\\grin_d\\AppData\\Roaming\\GitCredStore\\git-credential-winstore.exe'
```

The result was that I had to insert again every time the password and username. When I run again: git-credential-winstore it shows me again the wrong password.

Any idea how can I delete the wrong password stored in the cache?

Comment: Special case of [macos - How do I update the password for Git? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [control panel / User Accounts and Family Safety / User Accounts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon), or directly the Credential Manager:

[image: http://www.7tutorials.com/files/img/credentials_manager/cm2.png]

<sup>(Image from "[Credential Manager - Where Windows Stores Passwords & Login Details](http://www.7tutorials.com/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details)")</sup>

You should be able to delete the faulty credential there.

Update 2021:

The more recent credential helper would now be "`manager-core`", after "[Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core)" from Microsoft: a Git Credential Manager Core (GCM Core), a secure Git credential helper built on .NET that runs on Windows and macOS (Linux support is in an early preview).

To remove a password:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhostname=github.com" | git credential-manager-core erase
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Didn't though it exists in Windows. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I use http://[yourgitserverip]/Bonobo.Git.Server/Repository/[repositoryname] to change my password. Then;

1. Remove the git credential on Windows Credentials.
2. Find the .gitconfig file in (c:/Users/[YourAccount] folder)
3. Add this line (if does not exist):

   [credential] 
   helper = !\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\"