# Removal of a GIT repo's remote password

Tags: git

How can I unset the password associated my GIT repo's HTTPS remote?  It has remembered it somewhere along the line and I would rather retype it on every push.

Comment: What does `git config credential.helper` say?

Comment: It returns the string "manager".

Comment: Then it looks like you are using this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows - please try to check those docs and see if that's what you're using and how to use it.

Comment: In case others follow the answer in the duplicate question (editing the .gitconfig file), but start getting Java GitConfigInvalid exceptions (invalid .gitconfig file) when creating new files in the repo, remember to have a blank line at the end of the .gitconfig after doing a $git config --global --edit

Answer (score 6):

See "[Use Windows Credential Store for Git to remember your login for TFS, Bitbucket and such](https://kwilson.io/blog/use-windows-credential-store-for-git-to-remember-your-login-for-tfs-bitbucket-and-such/)"

Since your `credential.helper` is "manager", you simply need to [**open the Windows Credential Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33063731/6309) and remove your credentials associated to your remote repo.

[image: https://kwilson.io/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/4-store.png]