# How to Setting Up Git, VSTS and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup jenkins with my remote git server on VSTS.
But I'm not sure how to do this... I've been created a new Job, but when I try to connect with git, I have this error:
[image]

someone knows how to connect and setup this ?

Thanks a Lot !

Comment: When did the error occur? And What's the credential did you use, email&password, PAT or alternative credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a answer... I had to log in with credentials with this user

[image]

Comment: Yes, I suppose the login used for running Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

That means the Jenkins master machine where Git is installed has a credential manager (here, the [Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838624/6309)) which attempts to cache the credentials.

Check on that server:

```
git config credential.helper
```

You can either:

- type the `git ls-remote` command manually on that server (using the account which executes Jenkins), and cache the username/password there
- or deactivate the credential helper:

  ```
  git config --global --unset credential.helper
  ```

That will avoid Git to try and prompt for credentials in order to cache them.