# How do I stored the authentication credentials for Git on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

I tried to use this answer, but it didn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/148844

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>git --version
git version 2.15.1.windows.2

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>git config --global credential.helper manager

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>git pull
```

It pops up a GUI dialog box at this point.

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': email@domain.com
Password for 'https://email@domain.com@github.com':
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
...
 2 files changed, 11 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=2592000"

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>git pull
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Username for 'https://github.com': email@domain.com
Password for 'https://email@domain.com@github.com':
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Already up to date.

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>git pull
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Username for 'https://github.com': ^C
```

Answer (score 1):

First, keep the manager as credential helper:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Second, when the popup appears, enter your GitHub account username/password.

Then, the subsequent Git commands won't ask you for your credentials again.

You can check in the [Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838624/6309) if your credentials are indeed correctly associated to `https://github.com`.

```
Username for 'https://github.com': email@domain.com
```

Note: your username for GitHub should be your GitHub account username, *not* `email@domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded Git to version 2.16.3 and it worked.

```
chocolatey upgrade git
```