# GitBash/Github not responsive

Tags: git, github

Normally when I clone, add, commit or push using GitBash, I get the normal responses. Suddenly, after a routine reboot, GitBash's interaction with Github seems to be disconnected. It properly responds to the following commands.

```
git init
```

> Initializing/Reinitializing...

```
git add .
```

> Normal response

```
git commit -m "commit notes"
```

> Normal response

When it comes time to push to my Repositories on GitHub there's no response.

```
git push origin master
```

> No response

This also happens when I've attempted to create a repository with an existing local project. I can add an origin, and when I check it with remote -v, it acknowledges the origin as a github repository, but when it comes time to push -u origin master, once again there's no response. It used to ask me for a username and password, but nothing now.

I also cannot clone existing repositories.

I had to force a cache wipe recently. Could that be the problem? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS, Git version and URL used (https or SSH)

If it is used to ask for a username and a password, I would assume a git remote -v returns an HTTPS URL.

In that case, check the returned value of `git config credential.helper`: it could indicate a manager (like [this one for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838624/6309)) having cached the wrong credentials for the github.com entry.

Comment: Thank you, Von. I reinstalled and changed some things, and it's working now.