# PyCharm IDE Connecting to GitHub Repo

Tags: git, github, pycharm, git-push

I am trying to Push some codes into GitHub's Repo, but after following PyCharm's Documentation to set the **Remotes**,Setting Directory to Repo, and setting the **ssh executable** to **"Built-In"** (on Version Control Settings), I got the following error:

```
  dnb_api: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

the weird thing is: the repo actually exists and the link to connect is in SSH form: "git@github.com:user/repo.git"

It's important to note that I'm under a corporate proxy, but all proxy settings are properly configured (since I can install packages and connect with external APIs).
Even the

```
  'git config --global http.proxy <username>:<password>@proxy:port'
```

and

```
  'git config --global https.proxy <username>:<password>@proxy:port'
```

where properly configured in the command line.

Do you have an idea how to figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

First, SSH would not need to proxy to be set: said proxy would be for HTTPS connections.

Second, double-check in command-line that `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does work (see "[Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection)": so you see a welcome message?).
Any mission I have done with corporate client has always involved SSH being *blocked* by the client proxy.

The OP [Petter Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5461381/petter-mendes) indicates:

> I updated Windows Credentialswith Git's token and now it's working....

That means:

- the URL was an HTTPS one, not an SSH one
- the GitHub  account had 2FA activated, in which case only a token works as a password.

Comment: Well, I tried to connect but appeared `$ ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
`. I think it's due my `/ssh/`file location and/or the corporate proxy. In any case I also tried `ssh -Tv git@github.com "ProxyCommand nc -proxy <username>:<password>@proxy:port %h %p"` but got no success...

Comment: Yes, that is consistent with any outgoing SSH connection being blocked, which has always been the policy I have seen so far with corporate client.

Comment: @Petter_Mendes Great! I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although you did not indicated that procedure (`Windows Credentials`) it paved the path to look after other possibilities.

Comment: @Petter_Mendes I did not indicate Windows Credentials (which I knew full well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838624/6309) because you mentioned SSH URLs in your question.