# Unable to clone git repo stored in a TFS server (corporate network)

Tags: git, authentication, tfs

Trying to clone a repo from a TFS server (local network) and getting the error 403 instead of being prompted for a username and password.

I have tried different things. So far

```
git config --global user.email "email@company.ca"
git config --global user.name "Domain\Username" 
git config --global http.proxy http://y.y.y.y:8080
```

```
Cloning into 'app-dlls'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_git/project1/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Other machines in the same network have no problems accessing the same repo and are being prompted for credentials.

Note that I'm using VS Code (not visual studio), however I assume that git should work on its own by just cloning from the command prompt. Same errors if I try the GUI application.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check first your [`git config credential helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentialhelper) ([explained here](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)): if it is set to "`manager`", it is possible that credentials were cached by the Windows Credential Manager.

You can open said [Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33063731/6309) to check for any `http://x.x.x.x:8080` entry.

Comment: The link "git config credential helper" links to https://github.com/contact , and is currently taking visitors to https://support.github.com/ . Is it supposed to be a link to some documentation about the git config credential helper, or something that manages your credentials within GitHub itself?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thank you for reporting this: I have fixed the link in the answer.