# Private repository not found after transferring ownership to different account

Tags: git, github

I transferred the ownership of a private repository to a different github-account. The repository is still private. When I try to push changes from the local repo to the new remote repository it gives me fatal: `repository 'url' not found` error. I already changed the url, the user name and user email. What can I do do solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you change the url? `git remove -v` in your local repository shows your the remote locations configured.

Comment: @PascalWittmann probably mean `remote`, not `remove`?

Comment: @camille Oh, of course. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting my GitHub related Credentials in Windows Credential Manager. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git) for further information. After deleting the credentials and running `git push` I hat to re-enter my password and everything worked fine again.