# Entered wrong password while cloning in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu from GitLab. Unable to clone, push, or pull

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I entered the wrong password while cloning in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu from GitLab. Now I am unable to clone, push, or pull.

The error is

> Authentication error

I tried every command and installed a new OS too and formatted my HDD too. Still that error persists. I am using Git version 2.25.1.

Comment: Have you tried entering the correct password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the password for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git)

Comment: If you are using VSCode 1.62, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69979522/6309

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Code are you using (menu *Help* → *About*)? 1.62.2? What version of Git? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70014414/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I used alternative , I clone my project repo using terminal and installed node-modules in vs code , and pushed the code using sudo. WORKED for me